# With relational datas ,how to prevent Rails from performing a DB request for each associated value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure if the title of my question really makes sense.
Let's say I have two basic models: Artwork, and Artiste.
An artwork has one artist.

When I display my list of artworks with the following erb:

```
<% artworks.each do |artwork| %>
<p><%= artwork.title %></p>
<p><%= artwork.artiste.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

I can see that Rails is performing a DB request for each artwork in order to get the name of the artist:

Puma log:

```
  CACHE Artiste Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "artistes".* FROM "artistes" WHERE "artistes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/artworks/index.html.erb:55
  CACHE Artiste Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "artistes".* FROM "artistes" WHERE "artistes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/artworks/index.html.erb:55
  CACHE Artiste Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "artistes".* FROM "artistes" WHERE "artistes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/artworks/index.html.erb:55
  CACHE Artiste Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "artistes".* FROM "artistes" WHERE "artistes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/artworks/index.html.erb:55
```

I guess this is ok for a few dozens of artwork, but not so much if this table grows...

Is there a clean solution to prevent all these requests?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classic `n+1` problem. 
You should eager load the `artiste` records while querying the `artworks`.

`@artworks = Artwork.includes(:artiste).all # or where or paginate`

You should read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) for details.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick immediately, many thanks, and I'm glad to know that's called a n+1 problem. thanks again.